# Managing activity background image

Tags: android

I want to set a 320x240 image as background of the activity in two ways.

First one is to set this image in the center on the activity, not enlarging it - keeping the original size of the image.
Second one, also in the center, but enlarning to 500x400.

Using simply `android:background="@drawable/background` enlarges the image to the activity size.
What do I have to do to achieve these effects?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

if you want to keep the image inside the frame without stretching. Then you can set the image in your code

```
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.your_imageview)).setImageResource(R.drawable.background);
```

In the second case, you may look into [how to set image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817824/set-image-width-and-height-in-imageview)